# Vue seems to be reusing child component when only one at a time is showing

Tags: vue.js

I am rendering child components in a v-for loop, but only showing one at a time. I assumed that Vue will create a seperate/new child component for each render.

But it appears to be using the same instance, since my data values in the child component persist even after being changed out.

Right now, i am creating a watcher to reset the data values manually when the question changes.. but that feels hacky.

Is this an expected behavior?

```
  // Parent Component
    <AnswerQuestion
      v-for = "question in questions"
      v-bind:question = "question"
      v-if = "question.id == currentVisibleIndex"
      v-on:questionAnswered = "questionAnswered"
      >
    </AnswerQuestion>



  // Child Component
  props: ["question"],
  data() {
    return {
      options: options,
      commentText: null
    }
  }

  // what i am doing now, feels hacky
  watch: {
    question: function (newQuestion) {
      this.selectedOption = null
      this.commentText = null
    }
  },
```

Comment: Is "question" a prop in the child component? Because if not I don't think you are telling the child what is the question.

Comment: yes it is. it works well, it is the object reusing that confuses me.

Comment: I think you should provide more code about your components, because the "options" data is not provided by anything and it's not binded to the question property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, reusing components and elements is expected, it's better for performance.

To force Vue to create fresh instances, use a unique value for the `key` property, for example the question id:

```
v-bind:key="question.id"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use v-show instead of v-if: `v-show= "question.id === currentVisibleIndex"`(triple equals is better).

`v-if` will render only when that condition is met, `v-show` will render all the `Answer` components but will only show the one with `currentVisibleIndex`.

You can move the `this.selectedOption = null`(selectedOption, actually) inside the `data`, that meaning that will be initialized with null. Another option is to use as prop and set the default return as null as well.