# vue js reusing component twice in same page

Tags: vue.js, axios

i  have a components  with axios call. i declare two of then with a props that give the uri to axios call

```
export default {
name: "CardData",

props :['uri','suffixe' ,'label'],

data : function (){
    return  {

        lab : this.label,
        suff: this.suffixe,
        data :0,
    }
},

methods :{
    init(){

        self = this;
        this.$http.get(this.$ApiUri+this.uri)

            .then(function (response) {
                self.loading = true;
                // handle success
                if (response.data){
                    if (response.data.nb){
                      console.log('we have nb :' + response.data.nb );
                      self.data = response.data.nb;
                    }

                    self.loading = false;
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {console.log(error);});
    },
},

mounted(){

     this.init();
},
```

i have a container that call this components twice

```
 <CardData uri="getNbNews" suffixe=" "  label="News" :key="100" ></CardData>
 <CardData uri="getNbSources" suffixe=" "  label="Sources" :key="101"></CardData>
```

i can see the result on console.log  to response.data.nb 
but only one is updated on front ... other contain 0
i can't figure it out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue seems to be reusing child component when only one at a time is showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159373/vue-seems-to-be-reusing-child-component-when-only-one-at-a-time-is-showing)

Answer (score 2):

Being the same component you need to distinguish them using a key property.

```
 <CardData key="news" uri="getNbNews" suffixe=" "  label="News" ></CardData>
 <CardData key="sources" uri="getNbSources" suffixe=" "  label="Sources"></CardData>
```

Comment: <CardData uri="getNbNews" suffixe=" "  label="News" :key=0></CardData>
            <CardData uri="getNbSources" suffixe=" "  label="Sources" :key=1></CardData> but nothing change even after ctrl+f5 reload page

Comment: You need quotes for wrapping your numbers if I'm not mistaken, :key="0"

Answer (score 0):

ok ..  i missed this noob thing

```
self = this
```

to

```
const self = this
```

coupled to  @Cristiano Soleti :key param anwser solve the problem. thanks :).